# Rough empirical formula for average temperature and pressure

Tags: climate, temperature, models, climate-models, barometric-pressure

Is there a rough empirical formula that approximates local average annual air temperature and pressure from geographical latitude, altitude and distance from ocean shore?

Comment: I mean it won't be very thorough at all... compare [Miami and Dubai](https://weatherspark.com/compare/y/105470~18622/Comparison-of-the-Average-Weather-in-Dubai-and-Miami).  Some similarities (just because it's hot at horse latitudes), but major differences because pressure and temperature are complex 3-dimensional solutions modulated by surrounding geography, geology, ecology, etc.

Comment: Not as far as I know, but it's one of my pet projects to use curve fitting to come up with one. However, it probably won't come up with anything useful.